# Ios captive portal Google oauth disallowed agent - angular app

Tags: ios, angular, google-oauth, captiveportal

I am facing the issue only in IOS devices.
Scenario:

1. User connects the wifi access point.
2. Captive portal is getting loaded in default webview of iOS platform

3.There is a button called "sign in with Google ".

4.Upon clicking the button , it attempts load to"accounts.google.com......" url

5. **Google OAuth 2.0 throws 403 error. Error: disallowed_useragent**

Help required in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @nvnagr , Can you please help in whitelisting the client id

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/9690282?hl=en which should allow you to sign in to such portals using the Safari browser.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the requirement it should work in the webview itself when connected through Meraki wifi access point.   When I try with pinterest.ph  as a captive portal ,Google authentication works in webview ( it doesn't report as "disallowed_agent"). Any suggestions on how this is achieved by pinterest.. I have read in other posts that Google can whitelist client ID so that it works in captive portal.