# Google OAuth client Id - Whitelisting

Tags: google-oauth, whitelist, captiveportal, embedded-browser

Requesting guidance on how to get the OAuth Client Id whitelisted, so that Oauth works in Embedded browsers.

My Client id is : 665249451488-84nosliqrc80hpe0ot1vperj1eb8gbfk.apps.googleusercontent.com

Any email address / contact details for whitelisting will be helpful.

Similar question : [Ios captive portal Google oauth disallowed agent - angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542479/ios-captive-portal-google-oauth-disallowed-agent-angular-app)

['disallowed_useragent' error on captive portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786197/disallowed-useragent-error-on-captive-portal)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google OAuth does not work on embedded browsers because this is known to be insecure. See https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html and https://security.googleblog.com/2019/04/better-protection-against-man-in-middle.html. On iOS, you should use safariviewcontroller instead of relying on embedded web views.

As explained on the other question, if the issue your users are running into is a captive portal, this is the recommended way to continue to use Google Sign In: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/9690282?hl=en.